# nngeo- nearest neighbor with distance dataframe

Tags: r, spatial-join, sf

I'm working with some spatial data and I want to turn the output of the `st_nn` command (outputs a list) into a data frame that I can join. For example

```
library(nngeo)
library(tidyverse)

cities <- cities
towns <- towns

nearest <- st_nn(towns, cities, returnDist = TRUE, k = 2)
```

The output of the list give me the unique ID of the two nearest cities and also the distances for those cities. I would like this as a tibble with the following columns: 1) `nearest_id`, (2) `nearest_distance`, (3)`second_nearest_id`, (4) `second_nearest_distance`.

Here is what I tired

```
tibble(col1 = unlist(nearest[[1]]), col2 = unlist(nearest[[2]])) %>% 
  rowid_to_column(., "row_id") # for joining later on
```

I need to find a way to keep the id/distances for the two nearest neighbors separate and give the id/distances each its own column. I tried a `st_join` with `st_nn` but that doesn't return distance.

Answer (score 1):

Make a data frame by combining two matrices constructed from the unlisted parts of the list:

```
> data.frame(
      cbind(
            matrix(
                   unlist(nearest[[1]]),
                   ncol=2,
                   byrow=TRUE), 
            matrix(
                   unlist(nearest[[2]]),
                   ncol=2,
                   byrow=TRUE)
            ) 
      )
  X1 X2       X3        X4
1  3  2 53071.50  99627.77
2  1  2 15069.49  57746.32
3  3  2 33345.18 113133.89
4  3  2 46392.06 104263.13
5  3  2 57459.81  98846.89
>
```

Or use `do.call` to row-bind each part of `nearest` and then convert to data frame:

```
> data.frame(do.call(rbind,nearest[[1]]),do.call(rbind,nearest[[2]]))
  X1 X2     X1.1      X2.1
1  3  2 53071.50  99627.77
2  1  2 15069.49  57746.32
3  3  2 33345.18 113133.89
4  3  2 46392.06 104263.13
5  3  2 57459.81  98846.89
```

Name the columns and re-order them in whatever way you'd normally do that.

Above is tested with the first five towns only so I can see everything in one screen and check the `nearest` list conforms with the data frame. Its easy to get things the wrong way round or fill the matrix in the wrong way.

```
> nearest
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
[1] 3 2

[[1]][[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[1]][[3]]
[1] 3 2

[[1]][[4]]
[1] 3 2

[[1]][[5]]
[1] 3 2


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
[1] 53071.50 99627.77

[[2]][[2]]
[1] 15069.49 57746.32
```

Looks good.

Answer (score 0):

The function below will:

- handle cases when there are different number of neighbors per id (if `maxdist` is given)
- return the row_number of the `x` object
- return the format in a long format

This solves issues with the functions provided by @Spacedman, which would fail when `maxdist` is used.

```r
library(nngeo)
#> Loading required package: sf
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.1, GDAL 3.4.0, PROJ 8.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)

nearest <- st_nn(towns[1:2,], cities, returnDist = TRUE, k = 2, maxdist = 40000)
#> lon-lat points
#>   |                                                                              |                                                                      |   0%  |                                                                              |===================================                                   |  50%  |                                                                              |======================================================================| 100%

nn_to_df <- function(nn_out) {
  out <- map(names(nn_out), ~enframe(pluck(nn_out, .), name = "row_id", value = .) %>% 
        unnest(cols=all_of(.x))) 
    bind_cols(out[[1]], out[[2]] %>% select(-row_id))
}

nn_to_df(nn_out=nearest)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   row_id    nn   dist
#>    <int> <int>  <dbl>
#> 1      1     3 34147.
#> 2      2     3 18266.

## other functions fail here
data.frame(
  cbind(
    matrix(
      unlist(nearest[[1]]),
      ncol=2,
      byrow=TRUE), 
    matrix(
      unlist(nearest[[2]]),
      ncol=2,
      byrow=TRUE)))
#>   X1 X2       X3       X4
#> 1  3  3 34146.94 18265.72

data.frame(do.call(rbind,nearest[[1]]),do.call(rbind,nearest[[2]]))
#>   do.call.rbind..nearest..1... do.call.rbind..nearest..2...
#> 1                            3                     34146.94
#> 2                            3                     18265.72
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>